# Pointer to pointer going out of scope in a way that I don't want it to

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

I have a function for finding a specified node in a binary search tree as well as that nodes previous node:

```
bool collection::removeFromTree(const char name[])
{
    treeNode ** prev = nullptr;
    for (treeNode ** curr = &root; *curr;)
    {
        int8_t result = strcmp(name, (*curr)->item->getName());
        if (result == 0)
        {
            deleteNode(prev, curr);
            return true;
        }
        else if (result < 0)
        {
            prev = curr;
            curr = &((*curr)->left);
        }
        else if (result > 0)
        {
            prev = curr;
            curr = &((*curr)->right);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem I'm having is not with this function, but with my `deleteNode()` function. I'm unable to assign my previous node to point to the node after my current node (or the node I plan to delete). This is the important part of my `deleteNode()` function:

```
void collection::deleteNode(treeNode **& prevNode, treeNode **& goneNode)
{
    //irrelevant code
    //if it has right child
    if (!(*goneNode)->left)
    {
        treeNode * temp = (*goneNode)->right;
        (*goneNode)->right = nullptr;
        delete *goneNode;
        (*prevNode)->right = temp;
        *goneNode = nullptr;
    }
    //irrelevant code
}
```

The problem, of course, is that `(*prevNode)->right` becomes `null` after this function runs. The pointer to the pointer goes out of scope and the data is lost. Any nodes that were to the right of goneNode go out of scope. Is there any nice way to fix this?

I've also tried:

```
void collection::deleteNode(treeNode **& prevNode, treeNode **& goneNode)
{
    //irrelevant code
    //if it has right child
    if (!(*goneNode)->left)
    {
        (*prevNode)->right = (*goneNode)->right;
        (*goneNode)->right = nullptr;
        delete *goneNode;
        *goneNode = nullptr;
    }
    //irrelevant code
}
```

When I do that, `(*prevNode)->right` becomes `null` right after I `delete *goneNode;` (before the function even finishes executing).

Comment: It will be better if you can post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of bits and pieces of code.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't do what I did in the [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908423/list-all-function-still-trying-to-retrieve-a-node-i-deleted-from-a-binary-search)?

Comment: `strcmp` returns `int`. Is there a good reason for restricting this code to only run on hardware with exact 8-bit integral types? Have you explored the possibility that converting the return value to 8 bits throws away information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage to using a two-star pointer here was to avoid using a `current` and `previous` pointer. Having a *pointer to* the pointer to a node, we can edit the link that bound that node into the tree. The rest of the previous node doesn't matter; we only care about the pointer to what I'll call the `bad_node` (the one to remove).

```
(*prevNode)->right = (*goneNode)->right; //50% chance that (*prevNode)->right was (*goneNode)
```

Either `bad_node` was to the right of `prevNode`, and we erase the location of `bad_node`, or it was to the left and we mutilate the tree. I'm betting in your scenario that the first one is happening. Once that line executes, `*goneNode` is going to be the wrong value, and so it ends up leaking `goneNode` and deleting its child.

To [rip myself off a little](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33909794/4756309):

```
else if (!(*goneNode)->left) //one child on right
{
    treeNode* temp = *goneNode; //store address of bad_node
    *goneNode = (*goneNode)->right; //replace bad_node with child
    temp->right = nullptr; //bad_node now has no children
    delete temp; //delete bad_node
}
```

The important thing to remember is that `*goneNode` is the pointer to `bad_node` *in the tree*. Assigning to `*goneNode` changes the structure of the tree.

Comment: I had two cases and only showed one, but thank you for this. I understand this for the most part. I'll spend the next hour wrapping my head around it.